# How to save records in two tables with1 to 1 relation in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I am working on this `ASP.NET MVC 4` project and I get to this point where I think I can't get my head around the problem. I am using `Entity Framework 5` and `Code first` workflow. I have those two entities:

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description
    public int UserFileID { get; set; }
    public UserFile UserFile { get; set; }
}
```

and respectively

```
public class UserFile
{
    public int UserFileID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have an admin part where I allow the admin to create new `Document` and most of the time the user will want to add some kind of file to the document but I want to manage the user uploaded files separately so I have an explicit entity where I plan to store all the uploaded files.

Something that seem very standard but I really can't figure out is this:

I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Documents", "Admin",
                    FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

Then in my Controller Action I would like to copy the file and create the records in `Document` and `UserFile` tables but I just don't see how I'm supposed to do it. I use repositories and `UnitOfWork` so in my controller I could first:

```
UserFile item = new UserFile();
//take the name of the uploaded file and set it for item.Name
unitOfWork.UserFileRepository.Add(item);
```

But then I have to save the `Document` where I can begin again with :

```
Document entity = new Document();
entity.Name = model.Name;
entity.Description = model.Description;
entity.UserFile = ???
unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.Add(entity);
```

What I really don't know is how to deal with the foreign key. I have a little experience but as far as I remember in other scenarion I just need to pass object of type `UserFile` like:

```
var entityUserFile =  unitOfWork.UserFileRepository.GetById(Id);
```

and then:

```
entity.UserFile = entityUserFile;
```

But I don't see a way to get the ID of the newly created record in `UserFile` table. I can think of workaround by setting unique name for each file, but I was wondering is there some way to deal with this. Maybe some `Code First` approach where I could create the two entity instances and let the Entity Framework deal with setting the relation, maybe some other way? Or I am obligate to save the `UserFile` entity then to get it back and pass it as value for my `Document` entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
UserFile item = new UserFile();
Document entity = new Document();
entity.Name = model.Name;
entity.Description = model.Description;
entity.UserFile = item;
unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.Add(entity);
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

The `DbSet.Add()` method marks all objects in the graph as "Added", so the `UserFile` should be Added at the same time as `Document`.

Reference:

[Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

Alternatively, EF should fix up your ID when you SaveChanges(). So this should work too :

```
UserFile item = new UserFile();
unitOfWork.UserFileRepository.Add(item);
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();//Database generates key 
                         //and EF fixes its in-memory version

Document entity = new Document();
entity.Name = model.Name;
entity.Description = model.Description;
entity.UserFileID = item.ID; //use the foreign key to avoid duplicate
unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.Add(entity);
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

You may wish to enclose this in `TransactionScope` because there are now 2 calls to `SaveChanges()`

Comment: In fact after I finished my writing here I tried what you suggested, just added `item.FileName = "SomeName";` and it seems to work. In fact I got record in both tables so it works, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the right way. Do you think this is how such kind of operation should be done? I don't know why but I don't like something in this approach...

Comment: Alternative version added that you may prefer

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was feared I'm going entirely in a wrong direction, I can't say that one is preferable, maybe if you or somebody else could say which might be better to use